# How to Give Customized Shape to The Boostrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to style Bootstrap navigation bar as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `<nav>` is what you need here, maybe put the top row in a `<div class="container">`, so that it will show with the margins on the side. Inside that div, place a flexbox to get it postioned to the left and right.